# How to design a tree to ask questions to make a decision?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tree, data-science, decision-tree

I'm trying to make a program that will ask a series of questions so that it returns a suggestion at the end. How could I do this?

I tried using trees, but could not make it properly.

For example, this can be a series:

```
Q : Is the care damaged fully?
A : No

Q : How bad is the damage? [Totaled | Average | Light]
A : Average

Q : Is it able to start?
A : No

Q : Is it towable?
A : Y 

.
.
.
.

Okay, recommended service plan : [name of package]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically you’re trying to accomplish and what you’ve tried so far? For example, do you have a fixed set of questions to ask and the issue is that your code doesn’t seem to be asking them correctly? Or are you trying to infer what questions to ask? What code do you have, what specific inputs cause it to fail, and what do you think the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a coding problem for an assignment or homework so I will not give the coded solution. You can try `if` `else` conditions to achieve this. It should be pretty simple with nested `if` conditions. You can also use `switch` `case` for this.

If you have the data in csv or text file and if you are allowed to use ML libraries, you can train a model and extract the tree rules from it in form of code.